# "geoserver" publishes "wms", uses "SLD file "and "vec:Heatmap", uses "Tiled" to load, and the picture is misaligned

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms

"geoserver" publishes "wms", uses "SLD file "and "vec:Heatmap", uses "Tiled" to load, and the picture is misaligned.
[image: error]

But using "Single tile" is normal.
[image: success]

"The SLd":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
   http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
    <NamedLayer>
      <Name>Heatmap</Name>
      <UserStyle>
        <Title>Heatmap</Title>
        <Abstract>A heatmap surface showing population density</Abstract>
        <FeatureTypeStyle>
          <Transformation>
            <ogc:Function name="vec:Heatmap">
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>weightAttr</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>AREA</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>radiusPixels</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>radius</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>80</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>pixelsPerCell</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>outputBBOX</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>wms_bbox</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>outputWidth</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>wms_width</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>outputHeight</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Function name="env">
                  <ogc:Literal>wms_height</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
          </Transformation>
         <Rule>
           <RasterSymbolizer>
             <Geometry>
               <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName></Geometry>
             <Opacity>1</Opacity>
             <ColorMap type="ramp" >
               <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="0" label="nodata" opacity="0"/>
               <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="0.02" label="nodata" opacity="0"/>
               <ColorMapEntry color="#378ccc" quantity="0.1" label="nodata"/>
               <ColorMapEntry color="#3ee6e3" quantity="0.3" label="values" />
               <ColorMapEntry color="#c0e63e" quantity="0.5" label="values" />
               <ColorMapEntry color="#e6893e" quantity="0.7" label="values" />
               <ColorMapEntry color="#e63e3e" quantity="1" label="values" />
                 <ColorMapEntry color="#e63e3e" quantity="9999" label="values" />
             </ColorMap>
           </RasterSymbolizer>
          </Rule>
        </FeatureTypeStyle>
      </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
   </StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: That is normal. In tiled mode the heatmap is computed for each tile separately.

Comment: @用户30184 Thank you very much for your answer! But now I don't know how to solve it. Have you ever had similar cases before?

Comment: Some similar cases: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=geoserver+heatmap+tiled.